# RecyclerView source code has empty onChange method

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, open-source

I'm wondering what does `notifyDataSetChanged()` actually do.
I was trying to navigate source code so I found it calling `notifyChanged()` method in a static member class that called `AdapterDataObservable`

`notifyChanged()` loops through data and call `onChange()` which is empty body.

So I can see nothing `notifyDataSetChanged()` did, how does my view change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method [setAdapterInternal()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29) is called when either `setAdapter` or `swapAdapter` are called, and it actually registers your RecyclerView as observer of changes in the adapter.

The data changes in your adapter, the adapter is the one responsible for watching your dataset, and it just let's the view know when the data changes, to adjust it's layout or bounds or whatever is needed to account for the data changes.